# Joins - two tables

Tags: join

I am new to Databases. I came across a peculiar problem with two tables. Please let me know the solution. Please fnd the scenario below

a ProductCentre table
 prdcntrId (primary key), prdcntrname

a ApplicationType table
apptypeid (primary key)
prdcntreid(foreign key to ProductCentre )
apptypname

```
ProductCentre table       ||            ApplicationType table
                          ||
 prdcntrId  prdcntrname   ||       apptypeid prdcntreid  apptypname
001          Delhi        ||          11          001           Busines
002          Mumbai       ||          12          003           Engg
003          Hyd          ||          13          001          Soft
                                      14          002         Science
```

The end result should be like this
A productcentre can have any type of applications like Delhi can have many busines, soft applications same with mumbai, hyd

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
prdcntrname                Busines     Engg   Soft       Science
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Delhi                      1             0       1          0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Mumbai                     0             1       0          1
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Hyd                        0             1       0          0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this solution possible from these two tables. Please help me in this scenario

Thanks,
KK

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Something like (Sql Server)

```
DECLARE @ProductCentre table(
        prdcntrId INT,
        prdcntrname VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @ApplicationType table(
         apptypeid INT,
         prdcntreid INT,
         apptypname VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @ProductCentre SELECT 001,'Delhi'
INSERT INTO @ProductCentre SELECT 002,'Mumbai'
INSERT INTO @ProductCentre SELECT 003,'Hyd'

INSERT INTO @ApplicationType SELECT 11,001,'Busines'
INSERT INTO @ApplicationType SELECT 12,003,'Engg' 
INSERT INTO @ApplicationType SELECT 13,001,'Soft' 
INSERT INTO @ApplicationType SELECT 14,002,'Science' 

SELECT  p.*
FROM    @ProductCentre p INNER JOIN
        @ApplicationType a ON p.prdcntrId = a.prdcntreid
PIVOT
        (COUNT(apptypname) FOR apptypname IN ([Busines],
                                                  [Engg],
                                                  [Soft],
                                                  [Science])) p
```

Comment: Yes nice one with the PIVOT function.

Comment: I agree. I was just reviewing PIVOT yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

If the `apptypname' types are fixed then this can work:

```
select
c.prdcntrname,
Busines = (select count(*) 
           from ApplicationType at 
           where at.prdcntreid = c.prdcntreid and apptypname = 'Business'),
Engg = (select count(*) 
           from ApplicationType at 
           where at.prdcntreid = c.prdcntreid and apptypname = 'Engg'),
Soft = (select count(*) 
           from ApplicationType at 
           where at.prdcntreid = c.prdcntreid and apptypname = 'Soft'),
Science = (select count(*) 
           from ApplicationType at 
           where at.prdcntreid = c.prdcntreid and apptypname = 'Science'),

from ProductCentre c
order by c.prdcntrname
```